# Display Typescript enum name in Aurelia binding?

Tags: typescript, enums, aurelia

Very simple... (assume all includes and imports are properly referenced).

Say you have a bindable variable of type Color on your view model (file.ts):

```
@bindable color: Color = Color.Green;
```

... and you are trying to display it on the view (file.html):

```
<input type="text" value.to-view="color"></string-editor>
```

where Color is an enum ... like this (Color.ts):

```
export enum Color {
    Red, Green, Blue
}
```

This will display the numerical value of the enum on the textbox, like this:

[image: Numerical value]

Say I want to display the name of the enum value, like this:

[image: Name of enum value]

I have these options...

1) Use a value converter

```
// enum-name-value-converter.ts
import { Color } from "color";

export class EnumNameValueConverter {

    toView(value) {
        return Color[value];
    }
}
```

... and then use it like this on the view:

```
// file.html
<template>
    <require from="enum-name-value-converter"></require>

    <input type="text" value.to-view="color | enumName"></string-editor>
</template>
```

2) Make the enum available to the binding context via viewEngineHooks:

```
// enum-binder.ts
import { View, viewEngineHooks } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Color } from 'color';

@viewEngineHooks
export class EnumBinder {

    beforeBind(view: View) {

        view.overrideContext["Color"] = Color;

    }
}
```

... and then use it like this on the view:

```
// file.html
<template>
    <require from="enum-binder"></require>

    <input type="text" value.to-view="Color[color]"></string-editor>
</template>
```

Now the question...

**Is there a third option for accomplishing this? Is there a preferred/recommended way?**

Comment: you can try making an enum where values are strings?

Comment: Why use enum in first place?  
['red','green','blue'].indexOf('green') === 1  
That is if you need to use numeric values of your enum

Answer (score 2):

Using a string enum you can then iterate over the keys or values depending on what you need.

```js
enum Color {
    Red = 'Red',
    Green = 'Green',
    Blue = 'Blue'
}
```

You can get the keys using `Object.keys`.

```
let keys = Object.keys(Color);
```

And the values like this:

```
let values = keys.map(k => Color[k]);
```

You can see a working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Color%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Red%20%3D%20'Red'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Green%20%3D%20'Green'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Blue%20%3D%20'Blue'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20keys%20%3D%20Object.keys(Color)%3B%0D%0Alet%20values%20%3D%20keys.map(k%20%3D%3E%20Color%5Bk%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60keys%3A%20%24%7Bkeys%7D%60)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60values%3A%20%24%7Bvalues%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A).

Answer (score 0):

How about when you set the enum's values to strings like so:

```
export enum Color {
    Red = 'Red',
    Green = 'Green',
    Blue = 'Blue'
}
```